# How to find the credible interval on the difference between the means of two proportions in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, proportion, credible-interval

I have two proportions of the beta-binomial family. x1=41, n1=88, x2=41, n2=90 (x= no. of successes; n=no. of trials). The beta prior shape parameters for the two proportions are alpha1= 20, beta1=26, alpha2=9, beta2=34 (I constructed the priors from a previous experiment). After running the binobp function of Bolstad package, I have the following 95% credible intervals: Proportion1 (0.3719884, 0.5397258); Proportion2 (0.2958429, 0.4595716). The means of the two proportions are 0.4552239 (Proportion1) and 0.3759398 (Proportion2). The Proportion1 mean seems to be higher than Proportion2 mean. But to be sure I would like to see if the credible interval on the difference between the means spans 0 or not (Thus whether Proportion1 is truly greater than Proportion2). Am I correct in taking this approach or is there a better way? Is there a package to check this or a code to do my job? Let me know if more info is required

Info about me: I have a Biology background with minimal math and programming knowledge but I am willing to learn so feel free to point me towards the correct resources. Apologies if this is not the correct place to post the question.